# Unexpected NoSaveStateFrameLayout with support Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am in trouble when trying to get the baseView(inflated in onCreateView and returned) in fragment, because I receive unexpected NoSaveStateFrameLayout.

I don't know why, can anyone explain?

Code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LogUtil.d(TAG, "onCreateView ...");
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gen_blank, container, false);
    return v;
}
```

When I run this code in all life cycles:

```
   LogUtil.v(TAG,  "getview = "+getView());
```

It logs the same msg:  `getview = android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout@41afdb70`

Answer (score 0):

The support library inserts an additional view into the view hierarchy. According to a comment in NoSaveStateFrameLayout.java: "Pre-Honeycomb versions of the platform don't have View.setSaveFromParentEnabled(), so instead we insert this between the view and its parent."

So you will need to either check for this with something like:

```
View myView = (NoSaveStateFrameLayout)getView();
if (myView != null) {
  myView = myView.getChildAt(0);
}
```

Or keep track of the view returned by onCreateView in an instance variable.